# :sprint and `seq` together - missing evaluation?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, ghci

I understand `` a `seq` b `` as "be strict on a and compute b", so `` undefined `seq` True `` throws and Exception.

I am playing around with `:sprint` and tried following test in ghci:

```
Prelude> x = [True, undefined]
Prelude> :sprint x
x = _
```

Okay, because `x` was not computed yet

```
Prelude> x `seq` True
True
Prelude> :sprint x
x = _
```

Why `x = _` at this moment? I thought that `seq` will evaluate `x` at least to `_:_` (or more possibly `True:_`), but its value still remains completely latent. It needs somehow check whether `x` is not `undefined`, so it needs to perform kind of evaluation, but why doesn't it keep the result?

I am using GHC 8.6.3

Comment: Cannot reproduce: I get `x = True : _` for the last `:sprint`

Comment: @chi which version of ghc are you using?

Comment: GHCi version 8.4.4. Weird. Try `:t x` to check that `x :: [Bool]`, as it should.

Comment: I can confirm this really happens in 8.6.2. It's very strange. If you use `() <$ evaluate x` instead, then it behaves as expected. I suggest you file a GHC tiicket.

Comment: Also: the `undefined` is irrelevant. The same happens if you use `x = [True, False]`.

Comment: @dfeuer `const True $! x` gives `x = True : _` as well. And yes, `undefined` is irrevelant – I have put it there because I wanted to check how deep the evaluation will perform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I made a ticket on trac (link: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/16089) and it seems to be a bug related to another one (https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/16096).

Problem was a result of how `x = y` and `let x = y` were treated in GHCi – the first one was interpreted as toplevel binding (with monomorphism restriction turned off by default) and the second one as `let` statement in `do` block. This issue implied some other unwanted behaviors like for example lack of shadowing warnings when `-Wall` was turned on. You may inspect fix for this at this thread: https://phabricator.haskell.org/D5473